# How to add file type extension using .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, routes

I want to map links like `http://example.com/STRING` to `http://example.com/STRING.png`, how to do it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.png [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.png -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1.png [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should, theoretically (I haven't tested it), redirect to first file in directory which is made of the given string (`http://example.com/STRING`) and 1 to 4 letters/numbers extension.

For example, these are your files:

```
.htaccess
file.php
img.jpg
anotherimg.gif
doc.html
```

if you request `example.com/doc` it will redirect you to `example.com/doc.html`
`example.com/anotherimg` redirects to `example.com/anotherimg.gif`

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ file.php?name=$1 [L]
```

file.php:

```
$files = scandir('./');

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if (preg_match(
        '/^'. $_GET['name'] .'.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}/',
        $file
    )) {
        header("Location: $file");
        break;

    } else continue;

}
```