# change of url structure

Tags: url, analytics

I am planning of changing the platform of my website. The new platform does not support the same url structure of the old one. 
Example: 
old website->example.com/category1/category2.html
new website->example.com/shop/category1/category2

old website->example.com/category1/category2/producta.html
new website->example.com/product/category1/category2/producta

The old website has some popularity in the net that I do not want to loose.
Will I have a problem with google analytics?
Is this going to affect the rank of my website?
Is there any kind of complication that I may get, with this change? 
Is there some tool/process, like google's "change of address tool" that I use to make a smooth transaction to the new url structure?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to write a .htaccess to keep using your old url structure:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.html [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps

Source: [How to add file type extension using .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984812/how-to-add-file-type-extension-using-htaccess)

Comment: There is a .htaccess file that wordpress is taking over and the site is not working when you try to change the url that much. woocommerce is recommend NOT to touch the url.